# What to download in Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, eclipse

I developed an app using AIDE but I need to publish it and I want to build it with a custom key, but I don't have premium key, so I used eclipse. I have ADT 23.0.4, but I don't know what to install among these.

http://s13.postimg.org/xf42jfe7a/Screenshot_9.jpg

This app should support all  API's from 8 - 21, please suggest me!! Thank You :)

Comment: check the extra folder for more google api's

Comment: it should gave what your looking for

Comment: Download only API 22 which is latest now. it will automatically give backward suppport if you give minSDK version as 8 and target SDK version as 22 in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download latest version of each from **tools** and **extras** folder and from API folder, download following from any one api level you want to run(I have ticked) and it is not necessary to download API 8 to API 21, you just need to download only one platform which you want to test on. And to run your app from 8 to 21 just define minSDK 8 to your manifest[image]:

Comment: Means i've to download all tools from `Tools` & `Extras` plus if I choose 4.4.2, I need to download as you said in the image???

Comment: No, in rev column there is version written. Just download latest version. Mostly three will be there in tools: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build Tools.

Comment: And in 4.4.2, if you want to run your application in emulator than only you have to download system image files named under: Intel x86 or ArmEABI, otherwise if you want to test app in your connected phone, no need to download system image files.